# I am facing problems in the register page

Tags: php

```
<?php
require('includes/core.inc.php');
require('includes/database/connect.db.php');
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Register'])) {

    $username=$_POST['Username'];
    $password=$_POST['Password'];
    $query= "INSERT into users (Username,Password) VALUES ('$username','$password')";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if($res){
        header("Location:index.php");
    }     
}
?>
```

I am facing problems while inserting data in the database don't know why the query is correct this problem is while selecting from database

> Notice: Undefined index: Username in C:\xamp\htdocs\chatbox\index.php on line 4

```
<?php
require('includes/core.inc.php');
session_start();
echo "Welcome".$_SESSION['Username'];
if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    if(send_msg($_POST['sender'],$_POST['message'])){
        //echo "Message sent ...";
    }else{
        //echo "failed to sent ";
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: duplicate php ???

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com - If you code this way you'll face problem of SQL injection. Your application can be hacked in a few seconds without any know-how. Visit the link to learn more about injection and how to prevend them (SQL-statements). Never, really NEVER(!!!) put user-inputs directly in your SQL query.

Comment: start session right after <?php tag...This may help you I think

Comment: and also start session in all the pages..this is must for using session variable

Comment: you store username in `$_SESSION['Username']` ?

Comment: You are using `$_SESSION`. But where you are assigning the value for `$_SESSION['Username']`?

Comment: to that one who log in

Answer (score 1):

try this remember you have to set session variable before using it.

```
<?php
require('includes/core.inc.php');
require('includes/database/connect.db.php');
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['Register'])) {

    $username=$_POST['Username'];
    $password=$_POST['Password'];
```

> $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;

```
    $query= "INSERT into users (Username,Password) VALUES ('$username','$password')";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if($res){
        header("Location:index.php");
    }     
}
?>
```

also to get rid of undefine index issue you should always use

```
echo "Welcome".isset($_SESSION['Username'])?$_SESSION['Username']:"";
```

hope your issue will get resolved.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: Username in C:\xamp\htdocs\chatbox\index.php on line 4

Comment: still getting the same problem